# Насколько безопасным является использование Salt Hash fingerprint + JWT

Tags: auth, jwt

Думал над способами обеспечения безопасности с помощью JWT и придумал немного странную концепцию. Что если использовать не просто JWT для хранения сессий, а вложить дополнительный слой безопасности в виде хешированого и солёного цифрового отпечатка(IP, User-Agent...). Получается что JWT обеспечивает достоверность нашего хеша, хеш приватность цифрового отпечатка, а в свою очередь отпечаток говорит о достоверности клиента который отправляет JWT. Токен не вечный конечно же. Хранится в httponly secure cookie.

---

Сразу скажу что не учитываю человеческий фактор, а так же возможность раскрытия JWT секрета или нашей Salt. Также для первичной авторизации используется сторонний сервер, к примеру Google.

---

Я понимаю что всё так красочно бывает где угодно но только не в нашем мире так что прошу указать на слабые места данной схемы. А так же как еще можно обезопасится от перехвата токена и его злонамеренного использования. Понимаю что это скажется на удобстве для пользователя из-за возможной частой смены цифрового отпечатка, если знаете какие данные подойдут лучше чем ранее предложенные сообщите. Заранее благодарю.

---

Пример токена:

```
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "iat": 1516239022,
  "hash":"SkDODVrANJYTo3yMdoucZsBokiTOD129bERy2AGeF9k"
}
```

Comment: «IP» — то есть юзера будет разлогинивать примерно мгновенно

Comment: andreymal видимо да, но он был приведёт лишь для примера, можете предложить другие типы отпечатка?

Comment: А всё остальное потенциальный злоумышленник сможет подделать если захочет, так что я думаю, что в этом нет смысла

Comment: @andreymal разве хеширование не достаточная мера защиты данных? Ведь хеш нельзя восстановить до изначальных данных, а использование соли делает невозможным dict attack (вот тут не уверен полностью так что если это нет так и соль не влияет на dict attack поправьте меня). Соответственно нельзя подделать данные , ведь их попросту не видно

Comment: Хеширование чего? Юзер-агента? Злоумышленник просто украдёт юзер-агент вместе с этим хешем, и никакой dict attack тут не нужен

Comment: @andreymal речь идёт о цифровом отпечатке в принципе, о том что перехватить могут в основном токен, а не о таких деталях как «IP» или User-Agent, это будет что то другое - отлично я за этим и пришёл, что бы получить мнение как такую концепцию улучшить/доработать. Может у вас есть идеи что можно использовать в виде отпечатка?

Comment: Кроме IP всё остальное можно подделать, поэтому см. третий комментарий